# Why I get warnings using “imageTitle” as an attribute name for a CoreData entity?

Tags: iphone, xcode, core-data

I get warnings in Xode 4 using “imageTitle” as an attribute name for a Core Data entity? In Xcode 3 there was no warning...any idea why?

The exact warning is: **Naming Conflict: imageTitle conflicts with a method already on NSObject or NSManagedObject**

Very annoying is that I get this warning for every single past Model Version...
**Any idea how I get rid of these warnings for past Model Versions?**

EDIT: You easily can reproduce this warning, if you create a new project using the "Navigation-based Application" with CoreData support and adding just the attribute "imageTitle"...

Comment: Are you sure you don't have in your code any class extensions/categories to NSObject or NSManagedObject that might contain a property or method named imageTitle or setImageTitle ?

Comment: Yes, I am sure, I don't have...

Answer (score 2):

I can't answer why imageTitle is specifically targeted.  My only guess is that it conflicts with some internal method or core data attribute.

In the past, if you had a core data attribute that used one of the reserved words, Xcode would let you build and your project would display very strange behavior.  The most common example is "description".  Cocoa assumes that description returns an NSString that describes your object, usually for logging.  If you had a dynamically generated core data attribute named description, then bad things would happen.  Especially if it was data or transformable.

Current versions of Xcode give the same error dialog if you try to name an attribute description.

While this is irritating, I highly recommend changing your attribute name to something else, such as pictureTitle or imageTitleString.  Even though "imageTitle" doesn't get many hits in the documentation, it likely conflicts with something internal.

As a last resort, file a bug with Apple.  It may actually just be a bug in Xcode.

Comment: Sure, I can easily change the name to something else, but what about all my past model versions? I get this warning for every single one and I have over 10 for versioning...

Comment: Ugh...  I can't think of a way to get rid of the warnings without messing yourself up.  You could look for the compiler switch to disable those warnings, but that's not a good long term safe solution.  I would definitely file a bug with apple.

Comment: @dickerhund Were you getting this warning all this time or is it something new?

Comment: After switching to Xcode 4, I get these warnings; all the time, when I load my project...